# turn animation 180 degrees in swift

Tags: swift, animation

I am using a curl up animation when swiping up, which makes a card fly away to the top - it works fine. I'd like to use the same animation, but to swipe down, so that the card flies away down. I guess I'd have to somehow turn the swipe up animation 180 degrees. Is that possible?

```
let views = (frontView: self.frontView, backView: self.frontView)

    // set a transition style
    let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCurlUp

    UIView.transitionWithView(self.flashCardView, duration: 0.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        views.frontView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.flashCardView.addSubview(views.frontView)
        }, completion: { finished in
            // any code entered here will be applied
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The UIViewAnimationOptions struct has another option that will solve this for you:

```
let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCurlDown
```

Comment: no, sorry, this is just flipping the card from top back down. I want the card to fly away and down.